# Automysqlbackup - Could not open required defaults file: /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, debian, mysql-backup

Trying to install AutoMySQLBackup on Ubuntu

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get upgrade
3. apt-get install automysqlbackup

I get the following error:

```
Setting up automysqlbackup (2.6+debian.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Could not open required defaults file: /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.34~rc-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
```

When I go into the following directory /etc/mysql/, I do not see debian.cnf. Is there a package I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like one of the following:

- On this server there is no MySQL server
- On this server there is some custom MySQL version (compiled or installed by hand, or some other versions like PerconaSever etc.), and this directory/file were not created during MySQL server installation.

Perhaps you can create by hand this file and install automysqlbackup, but this tool (automysqlbackup) uses data from /etc/mysql/debian.conf to access to MySQL and to create backup, so you need fulfill this file or configure automysqlbackup in other way.

BTW, please think about installing automysqlbackup 3.0, eg. from one of the forks: https://github.com/hersoncruz/automysqlbackup This is not so simply like just "install from repo", but this version gives better configuration possibilites than 2.6 version, you can use multicores (pigz in place of gzip for compressions) etc.